# create and select the same worksheet

Tags: python, gspread

In my code gspread creates a new worksheet for statistics, the name is "Year__Month_Day_HourMinute_'XTeam'_vs'Yteam' ", I did it this way so it's more easy to find the right worksheet. How to select this sheet for further usage. As this small program will be used at 2-3 matches in the same time (yay small time ultimate frisbee). Any idea?

I cannot do a simple "worksheet = sh.sheet1", as I don't know what will the # be. My solution would be to left out the minute of the name, that would make it easier, to just copy paste the name creator code part to the select code part, but I am hoping that there will be a better solution.

```
on_press: root.worksheet = root.np.add_worksheet(title=str(root.localtime.year) + "_" + str(root.localtime.month) + "_" + str(root.localtime.day) + "_" + str(root.localtime.hour) + str(root.localtime.minute) + spinner1_id.text + "_vs_" + spinner2_id.text, rows ="100", cols= "20")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a title that varies like that, as you have to dig all that data back up just to form a search for it. I would use only 3 Varying points in your title at most, such as 'DATE_xTEAM_yTEAM'. DATE would be a STRING value such as "042318" where you can split each element from the string (MONTHDAYYEAR).

This is a method I would personally do for accessing the data easier:
Manifest a JSON file which includes a DICTIONARY of all the spreadsheets (titles) ever created. The KEY would be a NUMBER (1) and the value would be the title. So if you wanted to find the second game in the season,  create a small python script that (using 'import json') would find the value for that key.
Basically a dictionary is the best way to organize the titles.

-Ryan

Comment: It sounds interesting, but I think I wasn't clear enough. After this program finished, only users will look at the files, so searching isn't really important. However, I want to select the worksheet immediatly on screen 2, so the program can write the statistics in it. Right now I'm thinking that maybe I give on_press one more stuff to do and make a variable witch contain the name too, so I can call the variable on the next screen. I know that isn't an elegant solution, but it would be kind of simple. What do you think?

Comment: Seems feasible, You should try it.